Composer showing error during version upgrade from 2.3.6 to 2.4.7-p1
While upgrading Magento, I updated all plugin versions to be compatible with the new version and PHP 8.3. I also removed unnecessary plugins and added some from the 2.4.7-p1 composer as well.
While running the following command:
composer2 update
or
composer2 update --no-plugins --with-all-dependencies
Showing Error:
    - magento/magento2ce is present at version 2.3.6-p1 and cannot be modified by Composer
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.4.7-p1 requires magento/magento2-base 2.4.7-p1 -> satisfiable by magento/magento2-base[2.4.7-p1].
    - magento/magento2-base[2.4.7-p1] cannot be installed as that would require removing magento/magento2ce[2.3.6-p1]. They both replace trentrichardson/jquery-timepicker-addon and thus cannot coexist.
    - Root composer.json requires magento/product-community-edition 2.4.7-p1 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.4.7-p1].

Note that magento/magento2ce is specified at the beginning of the composer.json file, not as a plugin.
"name": "magento/magento2ce",

Also there is no "magento/magento2-base" in composer but its showing in command problem


You need to follow this things.

First Upgrade from Magento 2.3.6 to Magneto 2.4.3
Then Upgrade from Magento 2.4.3 to Magento 2.4.7 - p1


i will try this solution, thank you

If answer help you, please upvote and accept as solution, so that will help other in community.

I worked on this solution with version 2.4.2, but in the end its gave me the same error again:
(The error message seeing indicates a conflict between packages that cannot be resolved by Composer. Specifically, it mentions that magento/magento2ce version 2.4.2 and magento/magento2-base version 2.4.2 cannot coexist because they both replace trentrichardson/jquery-timepicker-addon.
)

Problem 1
- magento/magento2ce is present at version 2.4.2 and cannot be modified by Composer
- magento/product-community-edition 2.4.2 requires magento/magento2-base 2.4.2 -> satisfiable by magento/magento2-base[2.4.2].
- magento/magento2-base[2.4.2] cannot be installed as that would require removing magento/magento2ce[2.4.2]. They both replace trentrichardson/jquery-timepicker-addon and thus cannot coexist.
- Root composer.json requires magento/product-community-edition 2.4.2 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.4.2].
